# playing with a controller but it shows me the pc controls in the tutorial and i have no idea what to do microsoft flight simulator

Tags: controllers, microsoft-flight-simulator

I am doing the first tutorial and I can't even get through that. I am using a controller, and it's asking me to do all this camera stuff and it literally won't tell me how to, but instead shows me what i would have to do on keyboard and mouse.

And either way, I don't even have a numpad on my keyboard.

Can someone help? I thought since this is a Microsoft game it would go well with a xbox controller.

Answer (score 1):

I’m having similar problems too. The short version is this isn’t a game so much as it is a simulator. There simply isn’t enough buttons on the controller to perform all the activities necessary to flying a plane. You’ll need to use a keyboard in conjunction with a controller to manage all the intricacies of flying.

Luckily, there are enough assists that this is manageable and you can operate the plane without the tutorial if you practice enough.